# How do I obtain a list of Tags from an InfluxDB Database

Tags: influxdb, influxql, flux-influxdb

we are currently looking at migrating our company data historian over to InfluxDB.  We have a Tag called 'tagname' and I would like to run a query to return a list of tagnames, how do I do this?  Is this even possible?  I have tried the following which seems logical to me coming from a SQL background however all this returns is an empty set:

```
q=SELECT "tagname" FROM "companyname"."autogen"."lvdata"
```

'companyname' is a placeholder for actual schema content.

I then tried to look for the last value of each tagname:

```
q=SELECT "tagname", LAST("value") FROM "companyname"."autogen"."lvdata" WHERE TIME >= '1970-01-01 00:00:00' AND time < '2023-08-14 00:00:00'
```

but this just returned a single value:

name,tags,time,tagname,last
lvdata,,1672271400000000000,tagname,248.564

Kind Regards
Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are schema exploring queries that might be better for this, like [SHOW TAG VALUES](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.7/query-data/influxql/explore-schema/#show-tag-values), eg:

```sql
SHOW TAG VALUES ON companyname WITH KEY = "tagname"
```

But I'd expect your query to work as well.